# xarray: replace only positive values with 1

Tags: python-xarray

I have an xarray which looks something like:

```
component_list = ['c1','c2']  
space_list = ['01_reg','02_reg','03_reg','04_reg','05_reg']

data = np.array([ [np.nan for i in range(5)],
                       [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0] 
                   ])

xr = xr.DataArray(data, 
                   coords=[component_list, space_list], 
                   dims=['component','space'])
```

I would like to replace all positive values by 1, keep 0s as 0s and nas as nas. I tried the following but nas also turn into 1s:

```
xr.where(xr>0, 1)
```

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554967/replace-finite-values-with-1-in-a-3-dimension-xarray) before, but the solution suggested does not work. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to find all null values and 0 values and perform logical or. This would be a condition. Wherever this condition does not hold true, replace value with 1.

```
xr.where(np.logical_or(xr.isnull(), xr==0), 1)
```